# How set paging in PHP?

Tags: php, paging

I have an 300 rows(data) each page contain 10 records I need first 10 pages then click next then display next 10 page here is my code:

```
<?php


$eu = ($start - 0);
$limit = 10;
$this1 = $eu + $limit;
$back = $eu - $limit;
$next = $eu + $limit;


if ($nume > $limit)
{
    echo'<div class="pagination right">';
    if ($back >= 0)
    {
        echo"<a href='$page_name?start=$back&o" . $_SESSION['clicked'] . "&p=$desc'>&laquo;</a>";
    }

    $i = 0;
    $l = 1;
    for ($i = 0; $i < $nume; $i = $i + $limit)
    {
        if ($i <> $eu)
        {
            echo"<a href='$page_name?start=$i&o=" . $_SESSION['clicked'] . "&p=$desc'>$l</a>";
        }
        else
        {
            echo "<a  class='active'>$l</a>";
        }
        $l = $l + 1;
    }

    if ($this1 < $nume)
    {
        echo "<a href='$page_name?start=$next&o=" . $_SESSION['clicked'] . "&p=$desc'>&raquo;</a>";
    }

    echo '</div>';
}
echo '</div></div>';

?>
```

Then I will get response like this http://app.ologie.us/app/admin/Screen.png

Can any one please guide to effective paging in PHP.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a tutorial on basic pagination.

http://www.phpfreaks.com/tutorial/basic-pagination

Comment: Linking to external websites isn't great, try providing an specific answer instead when possible.

Comment: So instead of giving a link to a very well detailed answer you'd rather me try to fit the same answer in 1/8th of the characters.  I find nothing wrong with what I did, if you don't like it vote it down, but I gave him the resource that he needed to learn how to do what he asked.

Comment: I find nothing wrong with it, but a shorter summary ALONG with a link would be preferred, at least if you ask me :-). Voting down isn't needed, just wrote my thoughts.

Answer (score 1):

Doing it like Tim said is, according to me, mainly a bad way to do this. Read in the data needed WHEN it's needed.
You could do it with a min - max index to your array.
Consider you want to display 10 records per page:

```
$min =  $page * 10; //Page is the current page
$max = $min + 10;
```

Then you just loop through the data between the min - max indexes.

```
for($i = $min; $i < $max; $i++) {
  //Echo your data like normal 
}
```

If you're gathering your data from MySQL, you might want to look up `LIMIT`.

Answer (score 1):

If `$limit` is your page size and you add another request variable `$page` - representing the search result page requested by the user - you can use

```
$start = ($page-1)*$limit;
for($i=$start;$i < $start + $limit;$i=$i+1) {
  ...
}
```

to iterate over a "page" of the results.

But of course it does not make sense to handle paging on the level of the result view. You want to limit the number of results you get from the query.

In addition I would really consider using a PHP framework rather than coding it in the way you present in your request. Chances are your application will end up to be difficult to maintain.

Comment: hi i am checking with your code but not work for me can you explain clearly

Answer (score 0):

You do it all client side with the DataTables plugin for jQuery.  This plugin also gives you a LOT more options like sorting and searching.

http://datatables.net/

If you have a VERY large table, this probably isn't a good idea, though.